# how to add metadata to file when uploading to google-cloud-storage via appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm uploading a file to GCS via app-engine following the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/app-engine-cloud-storage-sample#gcsexampleservletjava_imports_walkthrough)

(the code was taken from [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-gcs-client/blob/master/java/example/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/demos/GcsExampleServlet.java))

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
  GcsFileOptions instance = GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance();
  GcsFilename fileName = getFileName(req);
  GcsOutputChannel outputChannel;
  outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, instance);
  copy(req.getInputStream(), Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
}
```

and here is the copy method:

```
private void copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
        while (bytesRead != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = input.read(buffer);
        }
    } finally {
        input.close();
        output.close();
    }
}
```

now I want to add this metadata to the file

```
metadata = "{timestamp:\"01/12/2016\", blabla: 111}"
```

How do I add this metadata using the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `new Builder().addUserMetadata()` insted of `GcsFileOptions.getDefaultInstance()`;

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
  GcsFileOptions instance = new Builder().addUserMetadata("timestamp", "01/12/2016").build();
  GcsFilename fileName = getFileName(req);
  GcsOutputChannel outputChannel;
  outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(fileName, instance);
  copy(req.getInputStream(), Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel));
}
```